# I am am trying to link the image click to a new product page

Tags: reactjs

I have created a product card to show products on my homepage. I have created and product screen to display the single product and allow the user to add to cart. When i click on the on the image the page refreshes but there is no product on the screen. I have console loged and confirmed that the property id is undefined.

````js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Rating from "./rating";

export default function Product(props) {
  const { product } = props;
  console.log(product._id);
  return (
    <div key={product._id} className="card">
      <Link to={`api/products/${product._id}`}>
        <img className="medium" src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
      </Link>
      <div className="card-body">
        <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
          <h2>{product.name}</h2>
        </Link>
        <Rating
          rating={product.rating}
          numReviews={product.numReviews}
        ></Rating>
        <div className="price">${product.price}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
``` Product component
    
    import React from 'react'
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Rating from './rating';
    import { useEffect } from 'react';

    export default function Product(props) {
    
    const { product } = props;
    useEffect(()=>{
      console.log('ooooh, am I undefined?');
      console.log(product);
   },[product]);
   
   if(product) {
````

Comment: Please check source of your `props.product` data, it clearly says it does not contain _id field.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fiddle-forked-9ri7t - now that we can actually see the API request and respomse, as Shariati has mentioned _id is missing on the original object.

Comment: I am new to react and Im not sure how to pull in and id with the get request. When i consle log data object it has and id, can you explain how to make the id present with the axios call?

Comment: @EvanMatthews I think you've misread  in your code - product._id the underscore here doesn't exist on the original object. the get request returns an object with .id you dont need to do anything with axios, you just need to reference the returned object properly in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, you are passing the prop through from somewhere else into this component from some API call or async function.

What is happening, is its going from undefined to defined as part of some API call or something, and as a result, your getting undefined in your component on first render. You need to do something to keep a track of your changing state.

You'll need to do something around 'loading' state for that API call, which is outside of the component code that you've posted. In other words, your example isn't a complete picture of your code, and as such, it's hard to give you a complete answer.

Try this for debugging that assumption.

```
import {useState} from 'react';
export default function Product(props) {
 
const { product } = props;

useEffect(()=>{
   console.log('ooooh, am I undefined?');
   console.log(product);
},[product]);

if(product) {
return (
    
        <div key={product._id} className="card">
            <Link to= 
    {`api/products/${product._id}`}>
              <img
                className="medium"
                src={product.image}
                alt={product.name}
              />
            </Link>
            <div className="card-body">
              <Link to= 
   {`/product/${product._id}`}>
                <h2>{product.name}</h2>
              </Link>
              <Rating 
              
              rating={product.rating} 
              numReviews={product.numReviews}
              
              ></Rating>
              <div 
   className="price">${product.price}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
}else{
   return <p>Product null</p>
}
```

'''

```js
export default function HomeScreen() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fecthData = async () => {
      try {      
        const { data } = await axios.get(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products`);
        setProducts(data);
      
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Server responded with error",err);
        
      }
    };
    fecthData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      
        <div className="row center">
          {products.map((product) => (
            <Product key={product._id} product={product}></Product>
          ))}
        </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```